# sony qx1 api setcurrenttime

Tags: c++, sony

I'm trying to implement functions from the sony qx1 api using c++ and succeeded to do so for pretty much everything I need (shooting video, pictures, changing shutter speed etc.) The only issue I run in to is setting the date and time. The json request I'm sending reads:

```
    {"method":"setCurrentTime", "params":[{"dateTime": "2016-08-10T15:21:37Z"}]
, "id":1, "version": "1.0"}
```

which I believe matches the example given in the reference.
It doesn't return any errors and seems to get a response from the camera (when it isn't connected I do get a timeout response). However when analyzing the pictures it shows them all as taken on January 1st 2014.

I tried playing around with the request quite a bit, but haven't managed to find a request that the camera actually responds to. The camera does however change its date when connecting to the mobile app, just like it's supposed to, indicating me that it should be possible to somehow change the date and time setting remotely.

Any ideas?

Comment: What do the timestamps of the pictures read if you connect to the Playmemories Mobile App first to set the date before taking pictures?  Is the date correct or does it still read Jan 1st 2014?  We tried reproducing the issue but the API works correctly.

Comment: When connected to the Mobile App first the pictures do show the correct date and time, so it doesn't seem to be a camera issue. Can you confirm that the json request I send is in fact correct?

Comment: The JSON request appears to be correct.  I'm confused as to why the camera is not retaining the date and time after connecting to the mobile app.  Once you set the date and time the camera is supposed to retain that info unless you remove the battery.  Are you removing the battery somehow?  After connecting to the mobile app when does the date and time become incorrect?

Comment: I'm sorry, I might have been unclear. The camera does indeed retain the correct date and time after connecting to the app. And indeed only when removing the battery the date is reset. I just want our custom api to be able to reset the date and time, so it's one less thing to worry about when recharging etc.
Should the camera be in any specific mode to set the date?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  It makes more sense now.  The mode should not matter.

Comment: Do you have any other ideas what could be wrong, or what I could try? I still would really like it to be able to update remotely, since that also syncs it with the other systems (flight logs etc.)

Comment: Unfortunately, no.  If I think of anything will follow up.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your time and consideration.